# Why I can't see any ouput iterating this vector?

Tags: c++, vector, iteration

This is [my code](http://cpp.sh/3wha6):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>
using std::printf;

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> array{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};   

    for(auto i = array.begin(); i != array.end(); i++) {
        auto index = i - array.begin();

        if(array[index] == 2 || array[index] == 5) {
            i = array.erase(i);
        }

        printf("iteration | %ld\n", index);
    }   
}
```

why I can't get any output from this? Using cout instead of printf works...

Comment: I'm assuming that failure to include `<cstdio>` was some sort of typo or idiosyncracy of your compiler - otherwise you would have gotten error messages about `printf` being undeclared

Comment: @M.M didn't add cstdio. I don't need it :O

Comment: You need cstdio to use `printf`

Comment: *didn't add cstdio. I don't need it* That's wrong. Just because you don't get compiler diagnostics doesn't make it valid code. At the very least, it's not portable C++. It's on you to know what functionality comes from what standard headers and include the necessary headers. Use http://en.cppreference.com/w/ as needed.

Comment: It's not good that you're asking about the same piece of code over and over again. Don't do that, it's disruptive behavior that wastes everyone's time - including yours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are erasing `5` , `i = array.erase(i);` will leave the iterator at `end()`. But then you do `i++` which moves past the end, causing undefined behaviour.

To fix this, change your logic so that `i++` only occurs for iterations where `i = array.erase(i);` did not occur.

---

*Note:* You could just write `*i == 2 || *i == 5` instead of having `index`

Comment: I see. But why `printf` print nothing :O? Note: I feel better with `index`

Comment: When your program has undefined behaviour anything can happen, including mangling whatever output might have happened so far. For your program I personally get output up until segmentation fault but the behaviour can differ

Comment: @M.M He's calling `printf` before he does `i++`, so the undefined behavior hasn't happened yet.

Comment: Can undefined behavior cause time travel, so it goes back to the previous iteration and erases what it wrote?

Comment: Yes, if the program execution is guaranteed to hit UB then the entire behaviour of the program is undefined

Comment: @markzzz I wouldn't call it a fault, when your code has a mistake then its behaviour is no longer covered by the C++ specification